# php dynamically create date range for next 12 months with interval of 15 days

Tags: php

I want to create dropdown options dynamically with php as follows

```
01-March-2024 To 31-March-2024
15-March-2024 To 15-April-2024
01-April-2024 To 30-April-2024
15-April-2024 To 15-May-2024
01-May-2024 To 31-May-2024
15-May-2024 To 15-June-2024
01-June-2024 To 30-June-2024
15-June-2024 To 15-July-2024 ... And so on for next upcoming 12 months
```

What I tried is giving me as follows

```
01-March-2024 To 31-March-2024
01-April-2024 To 30-April-2024
01-May-2024 To 31-May-2024
01-June-2024 To 30-June-2024
01-July To 31 July 2024 ... And so on for next upcoming 12 months
```

PHP Code I am Using :

```
<select name="duration">
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++) {
    $time1 = strtotime("first day of +". $i." months");
    $time2 = strtotime("last day of +". $i." months");
?>
    <option value="<?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time2)?>"><?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time2)?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: What is the issue/question? Not sure where/how you're going to use the `duaration` value but the plain text seems like a bad way to do that.

Comment: You're halfway there. Add another option with `15th day of $i months` and create another option with that

Comment: @user3783243 I want dropdown written in first paragraph... With current php code given, I am getting options written in 2nd paragraph of question

Comment: @aynber thank you for solution. Please can you give example code with third addition option with 15th day of $i months

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time2)?>"><?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time2)?></option>` should give you 15s. (Updated as day and month were inverted)

Comment: @user3783243 thnx.. but your solution is giving as `15-Feb-2024 To 15-Feb-2024, 15-March-2024 To 15-March-2024` and so on.... I want `01-March-2024 To 31-March-2024, 15-March-2024 To 15-April-2024, 01-April-2024 To 30-April-2024, 15-April-2024 To 15-May-2024` ... and so on

Comment: @DzineTech Oh, missed you were doing last day of month, thought you were doing first of the next month. This should work:
`<option value="<?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time2 + 86400)?>"><?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time2  + 86400)?></option>` (adds 1 more day to the epoch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a little wrong in that `strtotime` apparently doesn't like `fifteenth of $i months`, but you can override the day in the date command:

```
<select name="duration">
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++) {
        $time1 = strtotime("first day of +". $i." months");
        $time2 = strtotime("last day of +". $i." months");
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?>"><?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time2)?>"><?php echo date("15-F-Y", $time1)?> To <?php echo date("d-F-Y", $time2)?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```